# How to send attachment with email in an ms access form

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, attachment

I was wondering would it be possible to create some sort of ms access form, where you would be able to upload any file and then be able to enter an email in another field, click a button, and send an email with said attachment to the entered email. So far I have the form created with an attachment field and below that I have a button and an empty field where the user can input an email that they would like to send the attachment to. My initial idea was to hard code the button to pull the attachment and send it to the desired email address using the .SendObject() function but i didn't find parameter for an attachment that I could send using the function.

[image]:

In the highlighted box is where users can add any number of attachments and in the box to the right of the send button is a text box that would allow users to put in an email address that they would like to send it to.

If there is a better way of doing this with forms please let me know, I'm always up for learning new things.

Comment: Try to use this function
[send emails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59975664/7526564)

Answer (score 1):

You can interface with the outlook objectmodel to create a `mailitem`, then `.send` the message and `.attach` a file, but the file has to be accessible to the filesystem. If the file were embedded in access, you would have to export it out, then attach it. [This link](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/mail.htm) and [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/161088) should give you a good idea of how this process works.

If you don't have outlook available, then you will either need software that has a VBA compatible API, or you can use a webservice to post the mail, but both of those options are far to massive to talk about here, unless you can provide more specifics.

Edit since your edit:
If you can use Outlook, and you can just store the path to the file() in the attachments field as an array, then you an loop over the array with `mailitem.attach` to attach multiple files

Comment: If Outlook is not available, but a SMTP server is, [Blat](http://www.blat.net/) can be used by building a command-line in VBA.